# How to count the occurrences of a value in a row based on a WHERE condition?

Tags: sql, qt, sqlite

I have the following `late_payments` table:

```
ref-no  |Jan    |Feb    |Mar   |Apr    |May     |Jun
1       |       |PAID   |PAID  |       |PAID    |  
2       |       |PAID   |      |       |        |PAID
3       |PAID   |       |PAID  |PAID   |PAID    |PAID
4       |PAID   |PAID   |      |PAID   |PAID    |
5       |PAID   |       |PAID  |       |        |
6       |       |       |      |       |        |PAID
```

I would like to check for each ID how many months are NOT paid.

For example, column wise, I can do the following:

```
SELECT ref_no FROM late_payments WHERE Jan IS NULL OR Jan = ''
```

I can also count the occurrences of Null string or PAID string in each column as follow:

```
SELECT Jan COUNT(*) FROM late_payments GROUP BY MyTable;
```

However, I want to to do the same but base on rows not columns. And with a little tweak. I want to count, for instance, the occurrences of empty string in a row taking into account the beginning of the year until the current month. For example, if this month is February, then for ID 1, it should count 1. Then if the current-month is  April, it should count 2. If it June, it should count 3, something like:

```
SELECT occurrences of '' WHERE ref_no = 1 AND current-month = Apr
```

Is it possible ?! if so, how ?

**P.S.:** I am implementing these selection statements on Qt for a c++ application. I am displaying the results of the select statements on `QTableView` using `QSqlQueryModel`.

**UPDATE**

Following **@VR46** answer bellow, here is what I did:

```
for(int i = 0; i < all_refNo_list.size(); i++) {
        qryTxt = "INSERT INTO late_payments "
                "select ref_no AS ref_no, sum(i_count) as unpaid_count from ("
                "SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN January = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS i_count, 1 AS month_no FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN February = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 2  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN March = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 3  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN April = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 4  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN May = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 5  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN June = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 6  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN July = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 7  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN August = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 8  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN September = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 9  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN October = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 10  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN November = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 11  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN December = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 12  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                ") A Where ref_no = " + all_refNo_list[i];

        query.prepare(qryTxt);
        if (!query.exec())
        {
            qDebug() << "Error" << query.lastError().text();
        }
    }
```

The result is the following table:

```
ref_no   |unpaid_count
1        |3 
2        |4
3        |1
4        |2
5        |4
6        |5
```

which is exactly is what I need.

But now I am unable to update these values whenever a month is checked as 'PAID' for specific 'ref_no'. i.e.: UPDATE the table whenever there is a change.

Comment: You should Check if your database model is best for your needs. I would Design it different. You could Set up a Payment table with ID and payment-date. I would not make a column for every Month. And please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The application should calculate the default members who failed to pay for 1 month, 2 months or 3 months maximum. The unpaid months do not have to be consecutive. So far, for selecting and displaying from the database, the QSqlQueryModel is working as pretty as perfect. This is just an explanation of what I am doing. Now, it is your turn. what do you mean by "not make column for every month". Please share with me how would you do it ? P.S.: this is my first time ever to encounter a financial database, not that I am expert but I would like to learn. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way

`Unpivot` the data and do the `count` with filter

```
select ID,sum(i_count) as unpaid_count
from
(
select ID ,case when Jan = 'PAID' then 0 else 1 end as i_count,1 as month_no
from payments
union all
select ID, case when Feb = 'PAID' then 0 else 1 end ,2
from payments  
union all
select ID, case when Mar = 'PAID' then 0 else 1 end ,3
from payments
union all
select ID, case when Apr = 'PAID' then 0 else 1 end ,4
from payments 
union all
..
) A 
Where month_no <= strftime('%m', date('now'))
```

Also consider changing your database design then querying will be much easier

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am just having serious difficulties understand your select statement, well, I am a newbe btw.

Comment: @Suda.nese - Updated with table name. It's just a sample query not a complete answer

Comment: @Suda.nese - Now what is the problem

Comment: It works now .. I just needed understand how your query works in details. .. thanks

Comment: Please check the update for the answer to your question .. thanks

Answer (score 2):

As etalon has said your database design is not optimal. Payment information should not be included in the table in which you have it. You have, what we call in database administration, a first normal form violation.

Put the payment information into its own table. If you need to you can build a view that reconstructs the table you have now.

Comment: Please explain more how can I put payment information into its own table, thanks.

Comment: Your Payments table needs a Molecular (compound) key (two or more columns in the primary key). Is ID an AUI?  (Arbitrary Unique Identifier, a system generated key not seen by the end user). If so you may be able to easily convert the Payments table by removing all but one column for payment indicator and adding a column for the month code. If ID is not an AUI then add the new month code column to the PK.

Comment: I am trying to comprehend your approach. The ID is generated by the data-entry user and not by the system but it is unique though (it has to be this way). So you want me to add a column called for example "Month" to hold what value exactly, would you please give me a simple example ?

Comment: Month would hold the code of the month in which the payment was made. I recommend you study and apply the Rules of Normalization: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Thanks for the link .. as you said, I need to redesign my db, however, i figure out that, at the moment, it's too late. I am gonna read the link anyway as I need to understand rules of normalization very well in order to redesign my db

Comment: Often the Rules of Normalization are summarized into the statement: "Each column (attribute) depends on the key (columns in the primary unique index), the whole key, and nothing but the key."